Tauri で登録したはずのコマンドが認識されていない
lib.rsで登録したコマンドをApp.tsxでinvoke関数を利用して呼び出してもcommand not foundと出力されます。
何が原因なんでしょうか。

lib.rs

#[cfg_attr(mobile, tauri::mobile_entry_point)]
pub fn run() {
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .plugin(tauri_plugin_shell::init())
        .invoke_handler(tauri::generate_handler![
            handler::book::all_book,
            handler::book::find_book,
            handler::book::create_book,
            handler::book::delete_book,
            handler::reading_note::get_reading_notes,
            handler::reading_note::create_reading_note,
            handler::reading_note::delete_reading_note,
        ])
        .setup(setup)
        .run(tauri::generate_context!())
        .expect("error while running tauri application");
}


App.tsx

    const getBooksInfo = async () => {
        invoke<Book[]>("all_book")
            .then((books) => setBooks(books))
            .catch((e) => {
                alert(e);
                setBooks([]);
            });
    };


自己解決(2024/12/15)
AppDataのLocalフォルダを使用したかったのでpermissionファイルを作成したのですが、そのためにコマンドのアクセスにまで制限がかかっていたみたいです。
フロントからファイルにアクセスする場合はpermissionファイルで設定しないといけないのですが、コマンド側でファイル操作を行う場合は必要なさそうなので削除することで解決しました。
